# I can not get the sum of specific attribute while I do group by

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a coollection as follow in mongodb:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5490a00879dc6a138dcefb0f"),
    "Date" : 20141012,
    "Type" : "Twitter",
    "Entities" : [ 
    {
        "ID" : 2,
        "Name" : "test1",
        "Sentiment" : {
            "Value" : 0.1,
            "Neutral" : 12
        }
    }    
    ]
}
```

and I have couple of them. Now I want to group by date and then after return summation of values in Sentiment for each date which is grouped for that I did it this way:

```
    DBCollection collectionG;
    collectionG = db.getCollection("GraphDataCollection");
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$Date");
    groupFields.put("Sentiment.value", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", 1));
    DBObject groupBy = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields ); 
    AggregationOutput output = collectionG.aggregate(where,  groupBy);
```

now my problem is that the sum of sentiment.Value is not return and just the count of collections aggregated in each groups is returned. Can anyone help me how to get the sum of Values in Sentiment instead?

Update:

I replaced this line :

```
groupFields.put("Sentiment.value", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", 1));
```

with this :

```
groupFields.put("value", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$Entities.Sentiment.Value"));
```

and now I just get 0 for all though there are a lot of non 0 values for sentiment!!!

Can any one help me ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your hint helped me to use unwinding to solve my issue, I wish you put as an answer then I could select it as a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's having trouble because Entities is an array. So it doesn't understand how you want to `$sum` up values. Would you want it to sum up all of the sentiment values of each entity and then sum up those sums among all documents that match the date?

Answer (score 1):

Try this mongo query

```
db.test.aggregate(
   [
     {
         $unwind : '$Entities'
     },
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: {'Date' : '$Date'},
           sum: { $sum: '$Entities.Sentiment.Value' }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```